# Android SMS BroadcastReceiver NullPointer

Tags: java, android, sms, android-context, android-broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to develop a basic SMS app, but i'm got a NullPointerException problem.
Well, there is the code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnSendSMS;
EditText txtPhoneNo;
EditText txtMessage;
sendSMS sendSMS=new sendSMS();



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
    txtPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo);
    txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},1);

    btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();
            String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();
            if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0) {
                sendSMS.sendSMS(phoneNo, message,getApplicationContext());

            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter both phone number and message.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}}
```

And there is the **sendSMS** class:

```
public class sendSMS  extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


//---sends an SMS message to another device---
public void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message,Context context)
{
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
            new Intent(SENT), 0);

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    //---when the SMS has been sent---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    //---when the SMS has been delivered---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
}}
```

And there is the log about the error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.lcssgml.appsmsmms, PID: 5861
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Intent android.content.Context.registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver, android.content.IntentFilter)' on a null object reference
                  at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:586)
                  at com.example.lcssgml.appsmsmms.sendSMS.sendSMS(sendSMS.java:41)
                  at com.example.lcssgml.appsmsmms.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:46)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

I can't figure it out the problem. I hope you can help me! Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made your `sendSMS` class an `Activity` subclass, presumably so that the `registerReceiver()` methods would resolve. You cannot instantiate an `Activity` with `new` and have it work correctly. The `Context` member it keeps will never be properly initialized, which is why you're getting the `NullPointerException`.

You're already passing a `Context` into the `sendSMS()` method, so you can just call `registerReceiver()` on that.

```
context.registerReceiver(...);
```

Furthermore, the `sendSMS` class should not be an `Activity` subclass, so you should remove the `extends Activity`, and the `onCreate()` override. Also, the `sendSMS()` method can now be `static`, so you don't need to create an instance of the class to use it, and can just call the method directly on the class. I would also mention that class names in Java should begin with capital letters.

```
public class SendSMS {

    public static void sendSMS(...) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

To call it:

```
SendSMS.sendSMS(...);
```

It would be advisable to unregister the Receivers when you're done with them, using `Context#unregisterReceiver()`. You might find it easier to do this by not using anonymous `BroadcastReceiver` instances.

I should also point out that the `SmsManager#sendTextMessage()` method will usually fail silently if you send a message that exceeds the character limit for a single-part message in the alphabet you're using.

Comment: Thx, i appreciate your answer! With your useful description i fixed the problem.